# Test if command output contains string with "set -e"

Tags: bash, shell

I need to check utilized RAM percentage from shell script. But I want to use "set -e" for it and this makes me a problem.

There are two version of free utility that has slightly different output. In order to use awk on output, I check which one of free command is, by grepping output for string "buffers" which appears in only one of them. If there is no such string, command has exit status = 1 which kills my script from executing due to set -e parameter.

I tried also adding "|| true" after grep command but this always sets exit code = 0, making my grep test useless.

```
set -e
free -m | grep 'buffers' &> /dev/null || true
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
    MEMORY=$(free -m | awk 'NR==3{printf "%.0f%%", $3*100/($3+$4)}')
else
    MEMORY=$(free -m | awk 'NR==2{printf "%.0f%%", ($2-$7)*100/$2}')
fi
echo $MEMORY
```

So how I can do this properly without turning off set -e parameter? Also any better idea then presented to get percentage of utilized RAM into variable is welcome.

Comment: Using `set -e` is [not universally considered a good idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) -- ignore the parable and skip to the exercises below if in a hurry. Reviewing [the incompatibilities between `set -e` implementations across various shells](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/) may further make the point of how `set -e` *causes* bugs, as opposed to only solving them.

Comment: Also, `[ $? == 0 ]` is gratuitously incompatible, as `==` is not a valid comparison operator in [POSIX `test`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html); use `=` instead, if you *must* compare `$?` at all (as opposed to just putting the content to be tested into the body of the `if`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid the failed command causing an exit due to `set -e` if you move it into the `if`:

```
if free -m | grep 'buffers' &> /dev/null; then
    MEMORY=$(free -m | awk 'NR==3{printf "%.0f%%", $3*100/($3+$4)}')
else
    MEMORY=$(free -m | awk 'NR==2{printf "%.0f%%", ($2-$7)*100/$2}')
fi
echo $MEMORY
```

Also, it's not so great that `free -m` is executed twice.
You could store it in a variable for repeated processing:

```
free=$(free -m)
if [[ $free =~ buffers ]]; then
    MEMORY=$(awk 'NR==3{printf "%.0f%%", $3*100/($3+$4)}' <<< "$free")
else
    MEMORY=$(awk 'NR==2{printf "%.0f%%", ($2-$7)*100/$2}' <<< "$free")
fi
echo $MEMORY
```

Comment: +1. There are certain places where `set -e` cannot reach, and the command list of `if` is one of them (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin)